# Dyanamic Query by Passing a String as Conditon for checking

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameters, ora-01722

This is my procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SP_SALARYADVANCE_RPT_TEST
  (
    txtExtraQuery IN STRING,
    refcur OUT sys_refcursor )
OPEN refcur FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT( SAL.ADVANCENO ), SALARYADVANCEID, SAL.TRANSDATE, SAL.APPROVEDREMARKS, SAL.APPROVEDAMOUNT, SAL.PAYRECAMOUNT, EMP.EMPLOYEENAME, EMP.EMPLOYEECODE
      FROM HRM_SALARYADVANCE SAL, HRM_EMPLOYEE EMP, HRM_EMPLOYEEDEPARTMENTS DEPTS
      WHERE SAL.EMPLOYEEID     = EMP.EMPLOYEEID AND
        SAL.EMPLOYEEID     = DEPTS.EMPLOYEEID AND
        DEPTS.DEPARTMENTID = txtdeptid || txtextraquery;
```

Here my problem is I am sending `AND SAL.STATUS in (1,2,3)` as parameter This 1,2,3 may change i wish to pass it from frontend itself.

While excuting this query I am getting and error of

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your "parameter" `AND SAL.STATUS in (1, 2, 3)` is put into `txtExtraQuery`. Of course, you can't concatenate that to your existing query like you did, because then you'd concatenate `txtdeptid` with `txtextraquery`. And that doesn't have any meaning. That's why you get an `ORA-01722` error, when comparing that with `DEPTS.DEPARTMENTID`

What you want to do is run an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command. Check out these links:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_dynamic_pl_sql_procedures.htm

But on the other hand, I think you should re-design your procedure. This doesn't look very nice. Why not pass a `VARRAY` or some other `UDT` to your procedure?